# How does "while(getline(cin, name))" controls an unknown number of lines of queries?

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

In a problem of HackerRank there is a condition to take *an unknown number of lines of queries*. The problem's link is:

[Day 8: Dictionaries and Maps](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem)

I couldn't be able to solve the problem for every test cases, but I looked at the solutions and found that people are using **while(getline(cin, name))** to control *an unknown number of lines of queries* like below:

```
    string name;
    while(getline(cin, name))
    {
        std::map<string, string>::iterator it;
        it = phoneList.find(name);
        if (it == phoneList.end()){
            cout << "Not found" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << name << "=" << it->second << endl;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am not getting how *an unknown number of lines of queries* are controlled by **while(getline(cin, name))**.

Comment: when it reaches at the end of the file it set `eof`  that breaks the loop.

Comment: just read documentation of each element, focus on: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @MohsanAli How does it determine the `eof` or end of file? Does it assume an empty string as the `eof`? I checked it and it doesn't assume an empty string as the `eof'.

Comment: it is determined when there is no more data to be read. when attempt is made to read the file but fails then eofbit is set.

Comment: @MohsanAli How can I tell the console that there is no more data to be read?

Comment: you can have a check on stream for example `if(cin.eof()){std::cout << 'File ended';}`

Comment: This works when `cin` is redirected to a special file, such as a pipe (close the input side of the pipe), a normal file (reach the end of the file), a network connection (close it).  Not so much when `cin` is accepting keyboard input from the user, although then you *may* find that some control character like Ctrl+Z is interpreted as end-of-file.

Comment: In particular, HackerRank is not having a human type in the test data for every submitted program, they will certainly run your program with redirected stdin.

Comment: ofc @BenVoigt how can our application know when the user will stop from feeding into the stream, user have to explicitly generate  eof to indicate that he is done.

Comment: In the case of interactive input, there may be no eof, and this program can **continue forever**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin` is an input stream.

`std::getline` reads a line from `std::cin` and writes it to `name`. It returns the equivalent of `true` if this has no errors, `false` otherwise.

The `while` loop therefore reads lines until it fails or is broken out of.

You can force a fail with `std::cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);`, or `break` out of the for loop.

Comment: Slight correction: `std::getline` doesn't return true or false, but a reference to the stream it was reading from.

Comment: it returns something that has a contextual conversion to `bool`, documented as `true` for no errors, `false` otherwise.

Comment: That means an error message is making my code accepted! Are there other ways of doing it?